# Is "payless" synonym of "free"?

Tags: meaning, differences, is-it-a-word

Does "payless" mean "for zero price", and "free" (as in beer)?

I searched the dictionaries but could not find the word.

I also wonder whether "cost-free" means the same.

Answer (score 4):

"Payless" is not a word in standard English, which is why you can't find it in dictionaries. It may have been invented (possibly multiple times) for advertising or marketing purposes, and in those contexts it probably means "free" or "low price".

For example, there is a shoe chain in the US called *Payless Shoes* (http://payless.com), but the intention of the word in that context is to suggest that you "pay less", not that you pay *nothing*.

"Cost-free" is also not a standard English construction, but it would be interpreted to mean that something is free.

Comment: A good answer, which I have up-voted, but I would caution that "cost-free" might also be interpreted as "at-cost", which means priced such that there is no profit (or loss).

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a context where "payless" could be intended to mean "free". Perhaps for the obvious reason that normally it's used in advertising contexts to mean *"if you buy this from us, you'll pay **less than you would** to buy the equivalent elsewhere"*. In short, I don't parse it the same as, say, a **painless operation**, or a **loveless marriage**.

Comment: Two thoughts: *payless* could mean 'without pay'.  "I am payless this week." ( I did not receive a paycheck)  Also, 'cost-free' to my thinking means more than just zero-price,  there are plenty of other costs that can be incurred- costs to society etc, that may still be present with a zero-priced item.  "Cost-free" things in the broad scope are probably pretty rare.

Comment: What about "costless" and "pay-free"?

Comment: Are you simply trying to invent words? "Pay-free" doesn't exist, and is not needed. "Costless" would be hard to interpret, since it carries a bit of a suggestion of "priceless," which means "extremely valuable," but this is not at all what you mean by this word. Furthermore, it is also unnecessary, since "free" works perfectly fine. "At no cost" can be used, and "gratis" is also a decent synonym. So again I ask, what is your purpose here? Inventing unnecessary words seems a waste of time.

Answer (score -1):

"payless" is not a standard english word, it means that to pay less amount than the normal price, it's like a discount, sale but in financial use, such as credit cards statements, payless converted into installments.

Comment: Hi syntax and welcome to EL&U, you could improve your answer by adding the references and dictionary links thereby making your answer solid.